# jQuery sometimes $_POST is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sometimes i get report that in jQuery Ajax query $_POST is empty.
For example Google Chrome on OS X or Windows 7 Firefox sometimes the post is empty sometime it isn't.
I can't figure out what seems to be the problem

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        jqueryAjaxPostData: JSON.stringify({
            name: "gen",
            id: 1
        })
    },
    processData: true,
    dataType: "json",
    failure: function ()
    {
        alert("Ajax failure")
    }
});
```

EDITED : There is PHP code

```
$post = Variable::toArray(json_decode($this->Http->post("jqueryAjaxPostData")));
```

Comment: Can you add the PHP code you got?

Comment: even if i see in var_dump($_POST) it is empy

Comment: You forgot to close the bracket for `JSON.stringify`

Comment: ok, that was little typo when i writed this post

Comment: Use the browser dev tools to see what the request actually looks like. This will help you narrow down the problem. If the browser is sending a correctly formatted request with the variables you want, then it's probably your PHP code that's at fault. If the browser shows that the request is broken then it's your JavaScript code that's wrong. First rule of debugging: narrow down the problem so you don't concentrate on things that aren't relevant.  :)